# Add M-files to VC6.0

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

I want to use MATLAB code in C++. I use [Matcom](http://www.sai.msu.su/sal/A/2/MATCOM.html) (A tool used to covert M-files to C++) to add M-files to C++ current project. It compiles successfully but errors when running.

I created a matrix:

> ```
> bit_in_char = uint16([...
> 0 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 1 2 2 3 2 3 ...
> 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 ...
> 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 1 2 ...
> 2 3 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 ...
> 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 ...
> 5 6 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 1 2 2 3 ...
> 2 3 3 4 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 ...
> 4 5 4 5 5 6 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 ...
> 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 2 3 3 4 3 4 ...
> 4 5 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 ...
> 5 6 6 7 3 4 4 5 4 5 5 6 4 5 5 6 5 6 6 7 4 5 ...
> 5 6 5 6 6 7 5 6 6 7 6 7 7 8]);
> ```

The code is running successful in MATLAB, but has error "uint6 is not yet implemented" in VC. Are data structures the same in MATLAB and VC?

Comment: Does `uint8` give the same error? It doesn't look like you need `uint16` at present, not that that solves your the problem but could be a quick fix if you need one

Comment: Have you considered other types? `int32` or `int16`?

Comment: @XuanZhang: may I ask if you can share a link to Matcom tool homepage? I never heard of it..

Comment: @Amro Sure,http://www.sai.msu.su/sal/A/2/MATCOM.html ,it's a old software.I find much website in chinese.You could send email to me if you has queston.

Comment: @Dan It's right.But I afriad outcome is wrong.

Comment: @Shai uint8 is right!

Comment: @GeekCode Sorry I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: @XuanZhang: Depending on how old this software is, perhaps unsigned integers were not supported back then. Those types were introduced later in MATLAB... The currently supported product is [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/)

Comment: Read this about the history of data types in MATLAB: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/01/15/data-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely is caused by VC6. That's a compiler from the previous century. Upgrade to something still supported, and it will probably work.

Comment: the compiler and the tool in question :) Matcom is a software that has been dead for over 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Use matlab corder in MATLAB 2012b.